# Android Studio 28.0.1 All Package is not available

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

Long story short. Whenever I start my app and click on the login button it would work but when I try to click on the register button it would crash. So, when I go to my RadioGroup. Class above it. It would say Decompile .class file, bytecode version 52.0(Java 8) and source "Android API 28 platform are not found". When I click on download it would give me an error saying all package is not available for some reason. When I thought I download all of it.

how can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I answer this for android-29, because I assume it was the same problem. If you make your compile sdk version in the gradle file the newest version, there might be a period of time that there are no available source code, since Google publish the source code a while after the sdk is available. here is an example from 4th of Sep 2019:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

> The popup error is not related to the exception you got on your
>   application. Api 28 source code is not fully available. Hence you got
>   the error. Change complieSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 27 or 26
>   and sync the gradle.

OR

> Android Studio > File > Settings >appearance and behavior> System
>   Settings > HTTP Proxy

I would suggest checking any proxy is required to enable internet for your android studio. Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: Ok, I just changed compilesdkVersion and targetsdkVersion to 27 it sync and it said this " Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in: C:\Users\softw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk                                                 
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (9s 63ms)

Comment: check the box where 27 platform then click on apply. after installing rebuild your project